# I am getting issue phantomjs and karma

Tags: angularjs, node.js, gruntjs, phantomjs, karma-runner

I am facing issue while running grunt, it throwing me following issue:

> ERROR [launcher]: PhantomJS2 failed 2 times (timeout). Giving up.
>
> DEBUG [karma]: Run complete, exiting.
>
> DEBUG [launcher]: Disconnecting all browsers
>
> Warning: Task "karma:continuous" failed. Use --force to continue.

I tried to run `npm install phantomjs`

Which is successful. After that i run `npm install` as well but again getting above issue

Comment: Try running `npm install phantomjs2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got solution for this, if we get this error so first need to check **karm.conf.js** file, there you have to search for key browsers and in that section you have to see whether PhantomJS2 is defined or not.It would be something like this:

```
browsers : [
  'PhantomJS2'
],
```

In my case it was there but still i was getting error, i then checked my hosts file which you can find in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc` if you are using windows machine and i placed 
**127.0.0.1 localhost** and there i go.... its worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you will need to run the `PhantomJS` standalone version for karma to connect to it.

I would suggest a better option according to my opinion, which is to use `karma-phantomjs2-launcher`. You can get that by: `npm install --save-dev karma-phantomjs2-launcher`.

Please note that it is not a stable version. If it suits your requirement, you can use `karma-phantomjs-launcher`, which works perfectly fine. But it does not have support for PhantomJS 2.

Comment: I have run this command:   npm install karma-phantomjs-launcher --save-dev but it does not solve my problem

Comment: You should run `npm install --save-dev karma-phantomjs-launcher` and NOT `npm install karma-phantomjs-launcher --save-dev`.

Comment: Thanks for your help 'jagrut', but after running above command i am getting following warning WARN [launcher]: Can not load "PhantomJS2_custom", it is not registered!.  After that browsers get disconnected.

Comment: You need to put `PhantomJS2` and `PhantomJS2_custom` in your `browsers` list in `karma.conf.js` file.